# Simplify 1+Sqrt[2]I-Complex[1,Sqrt[2]]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

The expression `1+Sqrt[2]I-Complex[1,Sqrt[2]]` should be zero. In fact, `N[1+Sqrt[2]I-Complex[1,Sqrt[2]]]` yields `0.+0. I`.

But `FullSimplify` and `ComplexExpand` cannot reduce this to `0`.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 11):

Many what's-going-on questions really just turn out to be people wanting a fix for their code.  They just don't understand why it doesn't work. Given the simple code, maybe an explanation of how `Complex` works is actually being sought.

There's pretty much the same problem with `1/Sqrt[2] - Rational[1, Sqrt[2]]` and `1/2 - Rational[1., 2]`. `Complex[x, y]` is not a valid expression unless `x` and `y` are numbers, which is reflected in how `Complex[1, Sqrt[2]]` is typeset in the Front End. (`Sqrt[2]` is not a number either. It's a numeric expression. Compare `NumberQ[Sqrt[2]]` and `NumericQ[Sqrt[2]]`.)  Generally, you should construct a complex number with `I`, not `Complex`, somewhat like your first two terms. However, `1 + Sqrt[2] I` cannot be represented by a `Complex` number in *Mathematica*. It can only be represented by a composite, complex-numeric expression.

For `Complex[x, y]` to be valid, `x` and `y` can be any numbers, `Integer`, `Real`, `Rational` or even `Complex`. However, `Complex` parts will be automatically simplified:

```
Complex[Complex[1, 2], 1]
(*  1 + 3 I  *)
```

Another undocumented quirk is that if one part is `MachinePrecision`, then both parts will be made `MachinePrecision` (the docs show only numbers with both parts entered with machine precision):

```
Complex[1., 2]
Complex[1., 2`500]
Complex[1.`6, 2]   (* may have mixed-precision non-MachinePrecision parts *)

(*
  1. + 2. I
  1. + 2. I
  1.00000 + 2 I
*)
```

Under the everything-is-an-expression philosophy, `Complex[1, Sqrt[2]]` is treated as an expression, but not one with internally defined semantics apparently. So it is not combined with other numeric expressions as though it represented a complex number.

A valid number passes the `NumberQ` test (as well as `AtomQ`, too):

```
Complex[1, Sqrt[2]] // NumberQ
Complex[1, 2] // NumberQ

(*
  False
  True
*)
```

P.S.
For `Rational[x, y]` to be valid, `x` and `y` each have to be an `Integer` with `y` nonzero, though `Rational[1, 0]` will evaluate to `ComplexInfinity`.

Comment: I don't know if it's worth adding but the OP's `N[1+Sqrt[2]I-Complex[1,Sqrt[2]]]` succeeds because `N[Complex[1,Sqrt[2]]]` becomes `Complex[1., 1.41421]`, a valid `Complex` number.

Answer (score 8):

```
1 + Sqrt[2] I - Complex[1, Sqrt[2]] /. Complex[x_, y_] :> x + I*y
```

Comment: Strange that the ref page for [`Complex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complex.html) doesn't mention things like `Complex[1, Sqrt[2]]` are not `NumericQ`.

Comment: @ChipHurst The docs do say `Complex` represents a *number*, and `NumberQ[Sqrt[2]]` is `False`.  But it's very strange to find the docs are incomplete.

Comment: Ah right, number as in WL number, not the mathematical definition of number. Seems like it could be more clear.